# Error when using SqlTransaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, transactions

I have a problem with using transactions in ASP.NET

Every time I use the code bellow I get exception:

> This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

I looked everywhere (including stack overflow) how to solve this problem, but anything works.

I am trying to insert a record to db (I am using SQL Server). See a code below:

```
Database db = new Database();
db.Connect();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL_UPDATE_ADRESA, db.Connection);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pPersonID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = personID;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pStreet", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30)).Value = street;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pCity", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30)).Value = city;

db.BeginTransaction();
command.Transaction = db.SqlTransaction;

int rows = 0;

try
{
    rows = db.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
    db.EndTransaction();
}
catch 
{
    rows = -1;
    db.Rollback();
}

db.Close();

return rows;
```

Methods and property which are called in class "Database" are:

Property:

```
private SqlTransaction mSqlTransaction = null;

public SqlTransaction SqlTransaction
{
    get { return mSqlTransaction; }
}
```

Methods:

```
public void BeginTransaction()
{
    mSqlTransaction = mConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
}

public void EndTransaction()
{
    mSqlTransaction.Commit();
    Close();
}

public void Rollback()
{
    mSqlTransaction.Rollback();
}
```

I tried to SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON at SQL Server,
rewrite the code (usings, not using Database methods and other stuff, but I can't see where is a problem).

This exception is thrown every single time I am trying to use the command.

EDIT:

Variable "rows" is equal to 1 after executing, so the record is inserted properly, but just after it, program throws an exception at "Commit" so it's going to catch statement and here it throws the exception again when calling a rollback method. After this crash the db is rollbacked and nothing is changed.

EDIT2:

Could it have something with the command? Like there is just one updating so it is autocommited, or anything like this?

Comment: You're suppressing all errors with that catch so you will never find out whether there was an error.

Comment: I tried it without try/catch, it will raise the same exception, but instead at rollback part at commit part

Comment: The code looks ok as it is. This means that the error (which clearly exists) is in a part of the code that is not posted here. Either post all relevant pieces or create a small, self-contained repro. By doing the latter you'll probably find the bug yourself. Can your reproduce the bug in 10 lines? I bet you can't.

Comment: I found the problem... There was Close() method at finally part in Database.ExecuteNonQuery it automatically turned this transaction into null so later when I tried to use it the exception raised...

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be some trivial mistake like a that. Reducing the program to 10 lines always finds these issues because there is no room to hide.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void EndTransaction()
    {
        mSqlTransaction.Commit();
        Close();
    }
```

why use Close() their is no method. may be obj.close(); is their.

Comment: it calls inner method:

public void Close()
        {
            mConnection.Close();
        }

mConnection is just SqlConnection property